# Efficient way to decode 365 days JSON data structure?

Tags: swift, jsondecoder

I have to consume a strange data structure from an endpoint I no control over. The data has 365 days but it is not an array.

```
{
   "times":{
      "2022-12-31":{...},
      "2022-12-30":{...},
      "2022-12-29":{...},
      "2022-12-28":{...},
      "2022-12-27":{...},
      "2022-12-26":{...},
      ...
   }
}
```

I'm trying to avoid loading all 365 days into memory if possible or even having to create a `Decodable` type with all 365 days which would be a silly approach I think.

Is there a clever way to only decode partial of the response because from my code I only need to query a single day or a date range. This is what I'm starting with but mentally stuck how to approach it from here:

```
struct ServerResponse: Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case times
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let times = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .times)

        ...
    }
}
```

I thought maybe I could initialize the `ServerResponse` with a date interval and let the decoding take over, but the initializer is happening in the decoder so I can't create another initializer for the decoder to use. Another idea I had was to add an extra parameter to the `init(from decoder: Decoder, dateInterval: DateInterval)`, but that's not possible I don't think.. Any idea on how to handle this?

Comment: Just decode times as a dictionary and look in the dictionary.

Comment: `let times: [String: Something]` should do the work. You use `userInfo` of `JSONDecoder` to add "extra param" for your `dateInterval` if you still need it.

Comment: Did not know about `userInfo` in `JSONDecoder`! Thx!! Please post an answer and will accept.

Comment: You can also create a structure representing a calendar day, e.g. `CalendarDay` and then parse dictionary `[CalendarDay: Something]`. You can also iterate the dictionary using custom decoding keys.

Comment: "I'm trying to avoid loading all 365 days into memory if possible." To do this, you have to reimplement JSONDecoder from scratch. This isn't as hard as it sounds, but it's at a minimum a few hundred lines of code, and in the most general case >1000 lines of code. (see https://github.com/rnapier/RNJSON for an example) JSONDecoder always parses the entire document, even if you don't actually use all of it.

Comment: But you don't have to actually create final records for everything. You can write a custom `init(from: Decoder)` that just pulls out the one record you want, if that's useful. The entire JSON document will be parsed into abstract JSON, but it doesn't have to call your Decodable implementation for every record if you don't want it to. (But "parse everything into a Dictionary and pick out the one you want" like matt and Larme are suggesting is the easiest.)